# How to filter duplicated rows grouping by index in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a confusion regarding filtering and extracting duplicated rows in a pandas dataframe. For example, consider:

```
   col1     col2      col3   col4  col5    ID

    1        yes        0      1      2    201
    2         0         1      0      0    203
    0         0         0      0      1    202
    0         0         0      0      2    202
    1        yes        0      3      4    201
```

How can I select and arange into another pandas dataframe all the duplicated rows that have the same associated `ID` without considering a specific number of columns, let's assume for this example the last 2 columns (`col4` and `col5`). For instance let's say I have `(*)`:

```
   col1     col2      col3   col4  col5    ID

    1        yes        0      1      2    201
    1        yes        0      3      4    201
    0         0         0      0      1    202
    0         0         0      0      2    202
    2         0         1      0      0    203
```

I know that I can use the [duplicated](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) and [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) builtin functions for doing this. However, since I am dealing with a large amount of columns and rows I do not know if this is going to return me all the duplicated rows organized as I want. I tried to:

In:

```
temp2 = ['col4','col5']
# I am doing this because I have a lot of columns in my real dataset more than 800
a_lis = list(set(df.columns) - set(temp2))
a_lis

df.groupby(df['ID']).loc[df.duplicated(keep=False, subset=a_lis),:]
```

out:

```
AttributeError: Cannot access callable attribute 'loc' of 'DataFrameGroupBy' objects, try using the 'apply' method
```

My confusion comes with the `keep` parameter, I do not understand at all how this parameter work. Thus, my question is how can I use groupby and the keep parameter correctly to get `(*)`

Comment: what output are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @HaleemurAli thanks for the help this one `(*)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use `groupby` here. Simply use `pd.DataFrame.loc`. Remember that `groupby` is used for aggregating data via a function. But what you appear to want is to `reindex` and put duplicated rows at the top of your dataframe.

`keep=False` keeps all rows which have a duplicate elsewhere in the dataframe, considering only the columns in `subset`. In this case, the row with index 1 will be removed.

```
import numpy as np

# calculate duplicate indices
dup_index = df[df.duplicated(keep=False, subset=a_lis)].sort_values('ID').index

# calculate non-duplicate indices
non_dup_index = df.index.difference(dup_index)

# concatenate and reindex
res = df.reindex(np.hstack((dup_index.values, non_dup_index.values)))

print(res)

   col1 col2  col3  col4  col5   ID
0     1  yes     0     1     2  201
4     1  yes     0     3     4  201
2     0    0     0     0     1  202
3     0    0     0     0     2  202
1     2    0     1     0     0  203
```